# Value as string array in gson key value

Tags: java, gson

I'm new to JSON. I'm trying to assign value (in key value pairs) as array of strings using GSON.
The JSON should look like as below:

```
{ "name": "path", "value": [ "/my-path" ,"/my-path2","/newpath"] }
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Change gson to JSON in title
2. [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-json-example)

Answer (score 1):

Even thoe I will hardly recommend you to use POJOS, gson is flexible enough to allow you to do what you want:

```
    JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
    jo.addProperty("name", "path");

    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    jsonArray.add("my-path");
    jsonArray.add("my-path2");
    jsonArray.add("my-new-path");
    jo.add("value", jsonArray);

    System.out.println(jo);
```

Comment: Quite simple, and shows how Gson lacks nice fluent interface methods for the `add` methods family.